# Rounding rationals in (0, 1) to the nearest unit fraction

Tags: algorithm, math, fractions

What's a good algorithm for the following problem?

> Given a rational *a* / *b* strictly between 0 and 1, find a natural *n* that minimizes |*a* / *b* - 1 / *n*|.

The simplest algorithm I can think of is to compare *a* / *b* and 1 / *m* for *m* = *b*, *b* - 1, …, stopping when *a* / *b* ≤ 1 / *m*, and then compare |*a* / *b* - 1 / *m*| and |*a* / *b* - 1 / *(m + 1)*|. That's *O*( *b* ). Can you do any better?

Comment: StackOverflow is a _programming_ Q&A site. Please read our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what questions are welcome here. This looks like it may be more suitable to http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: [The math.stackexchange.com FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq) says I can get better answers about algorithm design here. And to be clear, I'd be happy to get code as an answer in any language other than Malbolge.

Comment: Clarly the only candidates you need to test are floor(b/a) and ceil(b/a).

Comment: @Oded: I don't see how this is not a programming question. Is your problem that he's asking for an algorithm rather than a program or that the problem to be solved involves maths?

Comment: you can try a binary search for the range (1,b), will give you O(logb). I am not sure this is optimal, there might be close formula for this problem

Comment: @Henning Makholm- That does not seem obvious.  Can you explain why?

Comment: @template my answer has a sketch proof of this

Comment: @templatetypedef: The reciprocal function is strictly monotonic. So when you need to know the closest member of the image of a discrete set under the reciprocal function, it has to be one of the two neighbors _in the domain space_ of the target point under the inverse mapping (which happens to be the reciprocal itself). Floor and ceil find, by definition, the left and right neighbor in **Z** of its argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let k = floor(b/a) and then n must equal either k or k+1. Try the 2 candidates and see which one wins. This is O(1).

That this is true follows from the fact that 1/(k+1) <= a/b <= 1/k which in turn follows from the inequalities k <= b/a <= k+1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can do this in O(1) by using continued fractions.  Any rational number in the range (0, 1] can be written in the form

```
1 / (a0 + 1 / (a1 + 1 / (a2 + 1 / (... an))))
```

Moreover, this representation has some remarkable properties.  For starters, if you truncate the representation at any point, you get an extremely good approximation to the rational number.  In particular, if you just truncate this representation at

```
1 / a0
```

Then the fraction a/b will be between 1/a0 and 1/(a0+1).  Consequently, if we can get the value of a0, then you can just check the above two numbers to see which is closer.

The second important property is that there is a great way of obtaining the value of a0: it's given by the quotient of b/a.  In other words, you can find the closest fraction as follows:

1. Compute x = b / a using integer division.
2. Check whether 1/x or 1/(x+1) is closer to a/b and output that result.

If a and b fit into machine words, this runs in O(1) time.

Comment: Way overkill to start speaking of continued fractions here.

Comment: @Henning Makholm- In retrospect you're right.  This was the first thing I thought of when I looked at this problem, but having seen your much simpler and more direct logic I agree that this is unnecessarily detailed.

Comment: It's a cogent observation that the "first" step of continued fraction (which underlies more generally the best rational approximations under restrictions on the size of denominator, cf. Knuth AoCP v.2) gives the answer to the very specialized question here.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, your best bet is to use Ceiling and Floor functions.

If your rational `a / b` is given as `0 <= x <= 1` then you can simply do this:

```
int Rationalize(double x)
{
    int n1 = floor(1 / x);
    int n2 = ceiling(1 / x);

    double e1 = abs(x - 1.0 / n1);
    double e2 = abs(x - 1.0 / n2);

    if (e1 < e2) return n1;
    else return n2;
}
```

(Where it's assumed abs, floor, and ceiling are predefined)

Comment: Why floating-point arithmetic? That's just an invitation for inaccuracy when the input was explicitly specified to be a rational.

Comment: As I said, *if* it was given as a number `x`. If it's not, then you never have to worry about using floating point numbers. You can just use the plain old integer version just as well.